# how to append the text from daughter files to a single mother file and deleting headers from daughter files

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cat, piping

During a structural simulation, I get the following response in a `file.txt`:

```
constant                                             
        date 03/23/2011

{BEGIN LEGEND}
 Entity #        Title
    1     blank                                                          
    2     die                                                            
    3     blank                                                         
{END LEGEND}

 slave           1 time 1.12999E+01  x  4.81992E-03  y  1.69202E+01  z  1.94541E+01  
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01   
 ....
 .....
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01


 .... are the thousands of lines
```

I get this file 1 time per second like file1.txt file2. txt etc...

I have to join all the files to make single file out of that so that if I copy the next file in this file I dont get any of the text from the upcoming files which is given below but the remaining text to be appended at the end

```
 constant                                             
        date 03/23/2011

{BEGIN LEGEND}
 Entity #        Title
    1     blank                                                          
    2     die                                                            
    3     blank                                                         
{END LEGEND}
```

This above mentioned text needs to be deleted from the upcoming files, stays only from the first one.

I should get:

```
 slave           1 time 1.12999E+01  x  4.81992E-03  y  1.69202E+01  z  1.94541E+01  
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01 
 slave           1 time 1.12999E+01  x  4.81992E-03  y  1.69202E+01  z  1.94541E+01  
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01 
 slave           1 time 1.12999E+01  x  4.81992E-03  y  1.69202E+01  z  1.94541E+01  
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01 
 slave           1 time 1.12999E+01  x  4.81992E-03  y  1.69202E+01  z  1.94541E+01  
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01 
 slave           1 time 1.12999E+01  x  4.81992E-03  y  1.69202E+01  z  1.94541E+01  
 master          1 time 1.12999E+01  x -4.81991E-03  y -1.69202E+01  z -1.94541E+01
```

can anyone guide me with `awk`, `sed` and `cat`? I am ok to use piping `>>` too.

Comment: What is the exact pattern indicating the beginning of the content you want to keep?

Comment: I want to keep everthing after first slave of each generated file.. and append it to the first generated mother file.

Comment: In other words, I have to delete everything above first slave and append it to the first mother file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the header is constant across the files, so is the line count of the header. Thus, the quickest (and maybe dirtiest) way to achieve this is the `tail` command:

```
head -n 10 file1.txt > outputFile
fileCount=$(echo file*.txt | wc -w)
for ((i = 1 ; i <= $fileCount ; i++)) ; do
    tail -n +11 file$i.txt >> outputFile
done
```

`wc -w` produces the number of words that the glob expression `file*.txt` results in, i. e. the count of the input files. The arguments `-n +11` tell `tail` to start output at the 11th line of each file.

Comment: file* will copy the test, however the order would not be file1,file2 etc.. it would be any order in which it would be displayed.. my results should be in the same ascending order being meaningful.

Comment: @hamadhassan I updated my answer to take the sorting into account, I think it should be satisfactory now.

Comment: In my first version I had forgotten the file names in the `head` and `tail` calls, which would have caused them to read from stdin instead of from a file, which would explain the stalling behavior. Please check whether you copied these changes. Sorry for the flawed first version :-(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want to print everything from the moment a line starts with `slave`.

Hence, you can say:

```
awk '$1=="slave" {f=1} f' f1
```

so that this is accomplished. It uses a flag `f` that is activated when it finds a line having `slave` as first word. From that moment on, the condition `f` will evaluate to True so that `awk` will perform its default action: `print`.

If you happen to contain all the files within the same directory, just loop through them and output accordingly:

```
for files in /your/path/*
do
    awk '$1=="slave" {f=1} f' "$file" >> new_file
done
```

It is not very clear if the first "good" line might also start with `master`. If so, the `awk` expression should be like:

```
awk '$1=="slave" || $1=="master" {f=1} f' file
```

Comment: will it follow file1, file2, file3? I want to append at the end of a single file.